# PHP- Value of SESSION variable not echoing properly when page is refreshed

Tags: php

I have a session variable that is updated when a link is clicked which adds GET variables to the current URL:

```
<?php
$_SESSION['test'] = 0;

if (isset($_GET['do'] && $_GET['do'] == 'this')) {
   $_SESSION['test'] = $_SESSION['test'] + 1;
}

echo $_SESSION['test'];
?>

<a href="?do=this">Click me</a>
```

When the link is clicked, the new session value that is echoed is still 0.

Why? How do I get this to echo the updated value? (1)

EDIT: Yes, `session_start()` is included at the top of the page.

Comment: Do you have `session_start();` at the top of your file?

Comment: 1) You have everything in your `isset()` call, which won't do what you think it does 2) You can't just have html in your php

Comment: When I tried running it, it worked perfectly fine. Not sure what the issue is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change it to be like this:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!array_key_exists('test', $_SESSION)){
    $_SESSION['test'] = 0;
}

if(array_key_exists('do', $_GET) && $_GET['do'] === 'this') {
   $_SESSION['test']++;
}

echo $_SESSION['test'];
?>
<a href="?do=this">Click me</a>
```

I like [`array_key_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) more than [`isset`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) because the key can exist being null and still pass the test:

> **From the php docs:** "isset() does not return TRUE for array keys that correspond to a NULL value, while array_key_exists() does."

You also were using isset incorrectly to test the contents of `$_GET['do']`. To top things off, you didn't start the session on each page load.

[`session_start()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) will initialize the `$_SESSION` variable and fill it with the appropriate contents. Since this was not in your code, the `$_SESSION` variable never had your `'do'` key.

The second-to-last problem you had was the very first line, you were always setting the `'test'` key to `0` causing the outcome to always be 1 after clicking `Click me`

and finally, you didn't close the php tag prior to outputting raw HTML which should have given you an error

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have not paste the whole code but here is how it should have been done.

```
<?php
session_start();

$_SESSION['test'] = 0;
if (isset($_GET['do']) && $_GET['do'] == 'this') {
   $_SESSION['test'] += 1;
}

echo $_SESSION['test'];
?>
<a href="<?php echo $_GET['do'] //assuming $_GET['do'] contains a url ?>">Click me</a>
```

You need to start with `session_start()`  Google to learn more about it.
You have put everything in the `isset()` Google isset() to learn more about it.

you need to close php tags before you can insert raw HTML. Inside HTML you can execute php with `<?php ?>` tags.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before, you have everything wrapped in isset()  should be

```
isset($_GET['do'])
```

not

```
isset($_GET['do']
```

Also, you're session is always being set to 0 on each page refresh.  You need to only set $_SESSION['test'] = 0 if $_SESSION['test'] has not been set yet.

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['test'])) {
    $_SESSION['test'] = 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You are missing `session_start()` at the top of your script. You're also not assigning the session if it doesn't previously exist, you're continuously setting it to 0 before incrementing.